# Blog & Portfolio setup

Tags: multisite, blog

Like so many others on the web, I've been trying to get a blog and a portfolio to play nicely together within the same website. Here is what I would like the urls to look like and some things that I have tried.

**Desired Permalink Structure:**

```
reggi.com/portfolio
reggi.com/portfolio/$post_year/$post_title
reggi.com/portfolio/category/$category
reggi.com/portfolio/tag/$tag
reggi.com/blog
reggi.com/blog/$post_id/$post_title
reggi.com/blog/category/$category
reggi.com/blog/tag/$tag
```

**Here are some things i've tried:**

- Two wordpress installs

Cons: Very large (doup of wp core files), multiple logins, separate themes

- Two wordpress installs using symbolic links on wp core files (to
  minimize size)

Cons: multiple logins, separate themes

- Wordpress multisite

Cons: force root, can't use `blog`,

- One wordpress with `/%category%/` in permalink

Cons: slow, categories & tags leave out `blog` & `portfolio` in permalink (ex `reggi.com/cat/$category`)

**Question:**

Is there something that i've missed is there any other way to have two blogs on one site?

Comment: You can get just about any URL structure you want, but it's going to involve writing your own rewrite rules, see [WP_Rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite) or search for `rewrite` on this site.

Comment: Is there any reason why you you just don't use one WordPress install??

Comment: Its slow to query `site.com/%category%`, and the category and tag pages are missing their respective `portfolio` & `blog` directories ex. `site.com/cat/$category` instead of `site.com/blog/cat/$category`

Answer (score 1):

You can set up your blog & portfolio with one WordPress installation only.

Fist check this codex article: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

for portfolio it would be best if you'll create Custom Post Type, then all you portfolio stuff will have permalinks like `example.com/portfolio/some-great-project`, but post permalinks would be the same - `example.com/2011/07/14/hello-world/`, maybe with some WP Rewrite you can improve this too

Comment: I want my blog to be in a directory `blog`. I also want nested cats and tags ie. `example.com/blog/category/hiking` and `example.com/portfolio/category/javascript`, with a custom taxonomy I would love to do `example.com/portfolio/language/javascript` but the `portfolio` part is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Mamaduka is on the right path! You will need *only* one WP installation with the following:

- Custom Home Page
- [Custom portfolio post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types): custom post types generate their own archive pages, which you can template!
- [Custom portfolio taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies)

Comment: I'm having trouble creating a taxonomies that are nested within portfolio. I also don't want my blog posts to be in the root along with its taxonomies. Any suggestions?

Comment: see my answer for the nesting of the taxonomy

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a page that will be your static home page - use any name - and publish.
2. Name the second page blog - don't add any content and publish.
3. Go to Administration > Settings > Reading

   - Set 'Front page displays:' to 'a static page' and choose the first page.
   - Set 'Post Page' to the blog page.
4. Create a custom taxonomy for your portfolio custom post type - ensure the following option values - and ensure it's registered before the portfolio custom post type is registered, so that the slug portfolio/language will be checked for first, before the portfolio slug.

```
     'has_archive'           => true,
     'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio/language', 'with_front' => false ),
     'query_var'             => true,
     'public'                => true,
```

1. (read as 5, the pre block messed up the ordered list) Create a custom post type for your portfolio items - ensure the following option values, and that it is registered after the custom taxonomy was registered.

```
     'has_archive'           => true,
     'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => false ),
     'query_var'             => true,
     'public'                => true,
     'taxonomies'            => array('category' , 'post_tag', 'languages')
```